# Attempting brute force attack on MIFARE classic 1k

Tags: security, rfid, brute-force, mifare, contactless-smartcard

I'm attempting to write a program to guess a block key of one of my MIFARE Classic 1K cards.

Is it feasible to to maybe run something like this?

```
int i = 0x0;
while (true)
{
  i += 0x1;
  Console.WriteLine(string.Format("0x{0:x8}", i));
}
```

I understand that there are impracticalities of running a simple count, but would this have any degree of success?

Comment: You need to check 281474976710656 possible keys. Assuming that you can check one key every 25ms (reader & card delays, etc.) - in the worst case scenario you'd need to wait ~22623 years for a result.

Comment: It's not really clear what your specific problem is (although I suspect it's poor understanding of how a [brute force attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brute-force_attack) works in the first place), given that your question title asks about MIFARE cards, but your code has nothing to do with them. I would suggest that you edit your question to clarify it, and to remove any irrelevant details.

Answer (score 9):

There is more effective attack methods against MIFARE Classic than simple bruteforce. There is 2^48 possible MIFARE Classic keys so bruteforce would effectively take forever. A faster attack is, for instance, the offline nested attack (see [here](http://code.google.com/p/mfoc/) for an implementation). However, this attack only works if you know at least one key of the card. Another attack is implemented by the [MIFARE Classic Universal Toolkit](https://code.google.com/p/mfcuk/). This attack does not require knowledge of any of the card's keys.